# Conflicting steps on how to solve $x'=Ax$.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I was taught that when we had a 2 dimensional system of the form 
$$x'=Ax$$

With repeated eigenvalues, I'd need to find an eigenvector, $v_1$ and another vector such that:

$$(A-\lambda I)v_2=v_1$$

The solution would then be given by $x=c_1e^{\lambda t}+c_2e^{\lambda t}(v_1 t+v_2)$.

But today I encountered an exercise in which we had $A=2I$. And thus, the last equation can't be satisfied unless $v_1=0$, which shouldn't happen as $v_1$ is supposed to be an eigenvector.

What's wrong? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the solution with the $t$ if you have a *defective* eigenvalue. In general these are eigenvalues whose algebraic multiplicity is strictly larger than their geometric multiplicity. You get that one in particular if you have an eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity $2$ and geometric multiplicity $1$.

However, it is possible to have an eigenvalue of algebraic multiplicity strictly higher than $1$ which is still not defective. In this case you still get essentially the same solution as when the eigenvalues are distinct. In your case where $A=2I_2$, the solution is $c_1 e^{2t} v_1 + c_2 e^{2t} v_2$, where $v_1,v_2$ are two linearly independent eigenvectors for the eigenvalue $2$.

However, in 2D, this can only happen if $A$ is a multiple of the identity.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong. In this case you have two linearly independent eigenvectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ (corresponding to an eigenvalue $2$), therefore you can write the solution as $$x(t) = c_1e^{2t}v_1+c_2e^{2t}v_2.$$